# How to redo the undo of the creation of a folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, undo

I made a folder on my desktop to move files off my phone into it.

Halfway through the process, I accidentally copy a file instead of moving it, so I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to undo it.

The folder disappears.

What basically happened is that Windows undid the creation of the folder instead of the copying of the file.

I tried pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>, but it just put a folder that says "New Folder" on the Desktop with nothing inside.

The original folder is not inside the Recycle bin.

Is all my data gone? Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: I never like using `Ctrl-Z` in explorer: I've been too often caught out by what it has undone. If you undid a copy, the original file should still be on your 'phone.

Comment: I'm not sure if the upvote was yourself @RobotUnderscore, but if you I helped I would be grateful if you could mark my response as the answer when you can, thanks!

Comment: I did! I'll mark it as correct once Recuva finishes and I know for sure it finds the files. It's got a few hours left right now.

Comment: I had this exact situation just happen to me and it took me a while to figure out what happened to my files.  I didn't hit ctrl-z, but F2 to rename a file, but it wasn't really F2 because the freaking "F-lock" wasn't on.  On my MS Natural keyboard, F2 is also "Undo".  :-(  The files were from a move operation from my phone, so they went by-by and I've haven't been able to get them back.

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this I always turn to [Recuva](https://www.piriform.com/recuva), which is the best data recovery software I've come across for simplicity and effectiveness. There's a [portable](https://www.piriform.com/recuva/builds) version too if you don't want to install it.

Here you can specify the path to your desktop and the software should list the files that were effectively deleted, allowing you to simply select and restore them to a folder of your choice - good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I ran it, it didn't find a single file.

Comment: I did notice that you said you accidentally copied it instead of moving it, so it should still be on the phone...?

Comment: That one file is still there on the phone, as are the rest of the files I never got to move off my phone. The problem is the other files that I moved into the computer folder aren't. I was moving all the other files and when I used Ctrl + C instead of Ctrl + X on one of of the files, I tried using Ctrl + Z to undo the copied-instead-of-moved file, which landed me in this predicament.